# Reference Passing

Tags: c++

I am reading the follow question [Towers of Hanoi question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481224/towers-of-hanoi-question). The first answer say use

```
stack<int>&
```

My question is why this?. What happened in the memory?

Comment: Are you asking what a reference is? That should be explained by your C++ book.

Comment: If you do not pass by reference then it will make a copy of the container which is not what is intended if you want to modify the actual variable.

Comment: A reference is technically just a pointer. Readup RAII and pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're passing a reference so that a copy of the `stack` object will not be made. If a copy was made, modification thereof will not affect the original `stack` object passed to the function.  It will only affect the *copy* which is local to the function.

A reference is like an alias to of an object; when declared as

```
stack<int>& source
```

`source` now refers to that object.

Answer (score 1):

The function used in the mentioned question had the following prototype:

```
void Hanoi(int nDisks, stack<int> source, stack<int> intermed, stack<int> dest)
```

i.e. it takes all passed `stack<int>` objects by value. The copy of passed `stack` is created and any changes made to this object within the body of this function change the copy, not the original object that has been passed to it.

That's why the solution was to pass these `stack` objects by reference instead of passing by value. Basically references (such as `stack<int>& dest`) allow you treat `dest` inside the `Hanoi` function just like its type would be `stack<int>`, there's just no copying and changes are visible to the caller :)